# Problem for finding. documents base on id in mongoose and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have document in my mongodb like below:

```
    {
      "origin": {
        "country": "Iraq",
        "providence": "Baghdad",
        "city": "Baghdad",
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          14.555,
          23.645
        ]
      },
      "destination": {
        "country": "Germany",
        "providence": "Koln",
        "city": "Berlin",
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          14.555,
          29.645
        ]
      },
      "driver": {
        "firstName": "saman",
        "lastName": "safkhan",
        "phoneNumber": "09923332244",
        "socialNumber": "1234567890",
        "driverId": "63e89cf58d744cf55e71a940"
      },
      "_id": "63e8a2514ecbd8fd82b57f25",
      "date": "2023-12-15T20:30:00.000Z",
      "seats": 4,
      "status": "start",
      "orderNumber": "iraq464711404590",
      "createdBy": "63e89cf58d744cf55e71a940",
      "passengers": [],
      "createdAt": "2023-02-12T08:24:49.269Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-02-12T08:28:08.442Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "startAt": "2023-02-12T08:28:08.439Z"
    }
```

I want get. document by Id i can get document using Travel.findById(documentId) but when i try to get it by
Travel.findOne({_id:documentId}) it's return nothing what is the problam
and this is my code:

```
const getTravel = async (req, res) => {
  const {
    driver: { driverId },
    params: { id: travelId },
  } = req;
  const travelInfo = await Travel.findOne({
    _id: travelId,
    $and: [{ createdBy: driverId }],
  });
  if (!travelInfo) {
    throw new NotFoundError(`there is no travel with id:${travelId}`);
  }
  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ status: "success", travelInfo });
};
```